# What is the difference between DataStax Python Driver and cqlengine?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra, cql, pycassa

Like we have mongoengine and pymongo but I can understand that pymongo is a wrapper for python and mongoengine is an ORM.

So in case of cassandra, what is the difference between these two libraries?
what is the meaning of `"Python Driver"`. are python driver and wrapper/mapper are different?

https://github.com/datastax/python-driver

https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine

If both are wrapper for python then which one should I use.

and now what is pycassa https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa/? is it again same thing ?

pardon me if these are silly or ridiculous question but I really got confused as both Python and cassandra is new to me.

Answer (score 2):

[python-driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver) is the preferred python driver for cassandra as it supports CQL3 and the cassandra native protocol.

[pycassa](https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa/) is a thrift based python driver that doesn't support CQL. This is effectively deprecated by [python-driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver) and is no longer being actively developed.

[cqlengine](https://github.com/cqlengine/cqlengine) is an object mapper for python that uses [python-driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver). This is used for mapping cassandra data to python objects.